# number of bound variables does not match number of tokens and number of tokens do appear to match

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I haven't worked with this method of prepared statements until recently and i am having a problem. I read some of the similar issues here on stackoverflow but they seem to refer to different things like duplicate markers (i'm using ? not :name so i presume that doesn't apply) and i have used xdebug in php storm to debug what is being passed.

The query is part of a filter i use in my script.

My querystring in the debugger shows this:

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE (hud_game_type = ? OR hud_game_type = ? OR hud_game_type = ?) AND (hud_table_type = ? OR hud_table_type = ? OR hud_table_type = ?) AND (hud_table_size = ? OR hud_table_size = ? OR hud_table_size = ? OR hud_table_size = ?) AND approve = ? ORDER BY hud_downloads DESC
```

So there is clearly 11 x ?

`$search_values` in debugger shows:

```
0 = "Omaha"
1 = "Holdem"
2 = "All"
3 = "Cash"
4 = "Tourney"
5 = "All"
6 = "6max"
7 = "FR"
8 = "HU"
9 = "All"
10 = "1"
```

So again clearly 11 values in the array, here is the final part of the code:

Here is the code but as mentioned above the built string is above and it seems to be legit, since this code is relying on values passed in a form its built in another function, i can add that if relevant but i wouldn't think so since i show the outputted query above

```
$result = $database->resultset("
SELECT * FROM $data_table WHERE $search_game_type AND $search_table_type AND $search_table_size AND approve = ? $search_sort_by",(array($search_values)));

// returns an array of the results, first we execute and then fetch the results
public function resultset($query,$values){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

    try{
        // this handles situation where no params need to be escaped.
        if($values == ""){
            $this->stmt->execute();
        } else{
            $this->stmt->execute($values);
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        $this->error_db_query_failed(true,$values,$e->getMessage(),"Error #12");
    }
```

Now the error returned from PDO is:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

This same resultset function seems to work fine in other parts of the code but i'm only passing one or two params in those.

Even if someone can point me in the right direction or suggest what the error might be i am happy to search further but a lot of the other errors refer to :name type binding so the process is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$search_values` is already an array, you should just pass it directly to the function, don't use `array($search_values)`.

Comment: Nice spot, and that explains why the other queries worked because i passed them into array() rather than building an array like i do for this one. That fixed it and appreciate your quick reply, will select this as the answer in 10 mins when it allows me